# How to change character_set_server of MySQL on mac

Tags: java, mysql, macos, utf-8

I want to insert some items with some Japanese and Chinese in MySQL 5 on mac os 10.8 using mysql-java driver.

But I found all the international character becaome ?????.

I googled and found it's the problem of character_set_server.

I checked it with the command: show variables like 'character%', and found the character_set_server is latin now.

I want to change it to utf-8 and found most of the solution on internet is to modify the my.cnf file to:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

But I cannot find my.cnf on my mac. I just find a my-default.cnf under /usr/local/mysql/support-files/.

I changed it and restart mysql, nothing changed.

Then I created a my.cnf under /etc and put the content above in it. Restart mysql, still nothing changed.

I don't know how to fix it and I am really in a hurry.

Comment: I found the way: to modify the my.cnf in the /usr/local/mysql... directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way: to modify the my.cnf in the /usr/local/mysql... directory.

Comment: On my mac, the config file was located at `/etc/my.cnf`

Answer (score 2):

i saw your issue when i was searching the same question:why chinese charater stored in mysql became ????(i already deal the charset issue in my webapp) and how to change character_set_server of MySQL on mac(i cant find my.cnf on my mac too);

Here's the solution:
1.copy my-default.cnf from `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/`  to  `/etc`(my-default.cnf is just a template);
2.rename my-default.cnf to my.cnf;
3.stop mysql server in System Preferences(or may encounter can't connecting to mysql sock issue)；
4.edit my.cnf, add `character-set-server = utf8` behind `[mysqld]` ;
5.save the file and running mysql server and restart mysql;
after doing this, i successfully changed my mysql character_set_server to utf8, and chinese characters in mysql were good;